# Python command for surface deform modifier target

Tags: python, modifiers

Can anyone help me in finding the python command for surface deform modifiers target selection?

Comment: @batFinger CAn you hep me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`target`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SurfaceDeformModifier.html#bpy.types.SurfaceDeformModifier.target) property of the modifier is what you're looking for. If you're given an object, a target object and know the modifiers unique name (here assumed to be "Surface Deform"), then you could access it like this:

```
import bpy

active_obj = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
target_obj = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.get("Sphere")
modifier = active_obj.modifiers.get("Surface Deform")

if target_obj is not None and modifier is not None:
    modifier.target = target_obj
```

Enabling the *Python Tooltips* in the preferences (*Edit > Preferences > Interface*) allows you to quickly find the required code by hovering over UI elements. Additionally you can use the Python console in the *Scripting Workspace* which has an auto-complete function ($\leq$ 2.82: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, $\geq$ 2.83: <kbd>Tab</kbd>) that allows to discover properties and functions available for an object.

Comment: Thank you so much. it worked

Comment: IIRC Maybe a little earlier than 2.83 for tab autocomplete. Glad of the change, (used to keymap it) However find it  fails  for `from foo import <tab>`  inserts a bloody tab.

Comment: @batFINGER Did you report this already? Could be that the developers are unaware of this.